# Doctrine - A relationship between entity A and related entities B and C

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity-relationship

I'm making a game in Symfony/Doctrine.  I have two tables "Model", which represents a 3D model, and "Texture", a list of textures that can be applied to each model.  There's a one to many relationship between them (one Model has many textures).

Now there are a bunch of other entities (Monster, Character, Prop etc.), that need to have texture AND model information.  I need to set up a relationship that says "This Monster has this Model AND this Texture" (but since Model and Texture are themselves related, I couldn't use a Dragon model with a Goblin texture - it would have to be a valid pair.)

The problem is that I feel having both ->model and ->texture properties is redundant because one can be calculated by the other.  There's no database-layer checks that texture A actually goes with model B.

I thought initially that I would only have ->getTexture(), and create a "fake" model getter, like a)

```
public function getModel()
{
    if ( $this->texture ) return $this->texture->getModel();
}
```

Other approaches would be -

b) Have both ->getModel() and ->getTexture() within the Monster entity, and add a validation rule that checks that the Model and Texture match up.  The downside here is that I'm effectively creating redundant data, and I have a lot of validation rules to add everywhere.

c) Add a ModelInstance class which creates a relationship between Model and Texture.  The downside here is that there are more queries/complexity overall, and the simple relationship between Model and Texture isn't there any more - it's been replaced by something more complicated.  We'd also have to add a unique constraint on Texture.

Would love to hear how other people approach this problem!

Thanks,
James

Comment: You start out by claiming that your model and texture classes have a 1-M relationship.  If that is true, then there is no reason you would relate "Monster" and texture if your original statement is true.  The relationship between monster and model will then allow you to access the relationship between model and texture.  If you set up the relationships correctly, when you load a monster object, the model and texture data will all be available via something like:  $monster->getModel()->getTextures()  This is laid out in the section of the doctrine manual that covers relating classes.

Comment: The Monster needs to know what specific texture to use though.  The same is true for Prop, Npc, and the rest of the entities that represent things in game.

Comment: Those need to be defined in the setup of a model.

Comment: Yeah, it's an option to define both Model and Texture in the Monster entity.  I just feel it's redundant to have both, so I think there has to be a better method.

Comment: You misunderstand.  There is no reason to setup texture in monster.  If it is related to model, it is already available, using the code i presented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a texture can belong to one and only one model then:

```
public function getModel()
{
    if ( $this->texture ) return $this->texture->getModel();
}
```

is perfectly fine.

Just need to make sure that whatever is calling getModel can handle a null results.  You will save yourself some headaches if you just require all monsters to have a texture and thus a model.

It does seem a bit strange to me that the same texture could not be used for different models.

You might also ask how often do you want to query by model.  If you will be doing it quite a bit then you might want to go ahead and just add model to monster even if it is a bit redundant.

Comment: Right now in the design a single texture only works on one Model. It's fairly simplistic and may change, but this issue is something that I run into quite often. It's not nullable, so that IF statement shouldn't be there.  So these non-standard getters are a good practice?  Does it matter that they don't have an associated setter?  (setModel() would be fairly irrelevant).

Comment: The only time you might need a fake set model is if you are using a form to access some model properties.  Otherwise, no need for one.